# Redefine arguments within an R core package function

Tags: r, updates

My fingers are starting to tire of typing `update.packages(checkBuilt = T, ask = F)`. I was wondering whether it's possible to redefine the default parameters within the `update.packages()` function. So far, I've tried adding the following to my *.Rprofile* file:

```r
utils::assignInNamespace(
  "update.packages",
  function(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE, ...) {

    update.packages(checkBuilt = checkBuilt, ask = ask, ...)

  },
  "utils"
)
```

But when I try to use the function in R I get the following error:

```r
update.packages()
```

```
Error: C stack usage  7976404 is too close to the limit
```

I've also just tried using `formals()` with the following in the *.Rprofile*:

```r
local({

  args_new <- alist(lib.loc = .libPaths(), ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
  ind <- which(methods::formalArgs(update.packages) %in% names(args_new))

  formals(update.packages)[ind] <- args_new
  
})
```

But that results in the following error upon launching R:

```
Error in formals(update.packages) : object 'update.packages' not found
```

Comment: Why not just define a new function in your .Rprofile called something like my_update_pckages that is a wrapper to update.packages with the arguments specified as you like?  Then you could call that function instead?

Comment: You have defined the function recursively.

Answer (score 1):

As @Roland said in the comments, your definition is recursive.  You shouldn't bother with the `assignInNamespace`:  keeping the new function in your workspace is good enough.  Then you can use `utils::update.packages` in its definition, e.g.

```
update.packages <- function(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE, ...) 
  utils::update.packages(checkBuilt = checkBuilt, ask = ask, ...)
```

You should avoid using `assignInNamespace` for the reasons listed in its help page.

Comment: I just tried your second example and got the following error: `Error in utils::assignInNamespace(x = "update.packages", value = function(ask = FALSE,  : 
  locked binding of ‘update.packages’ cannot be changed`

Comment: But you didn't get that with your original?  Weird.  Anyway, go with the first one.

Comment: Hi @user2554330. I could, and it would work. But it feels a bit hacky. Could also hide the function in an environment prefixed with a `.` to hide it. But both would just masking the function, rather than altering it's default arguments.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  Changing the original is much more dangerous:  what if some other function calls `utils::update.packages`, assuming that the defaults for those arguments have the original values as documented?  Then that function will be broken by your change.